# How to change stacking order of columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3, I have a really simple layout like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            Header Content Left
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            Header Content Middle
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            Header Content Right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1036/)

On smaller devices, instead of it stacking in the natural order I would like it to stack like this:

```
Header Content Middle
Header Content Right
Header Content Left
```

I am stuck on how to achieve this, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check out `push` and `pull` - see Column Ordering here http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Would love to know this too! Great Question

Comment: This link, http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering is what @Dan is trying to point at. I would definitely use http://www.bootply.com/ instead of jsfiddle for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap's `col-**` classes have `position: relative;` property. So when you set additionally `col-**-push-**` or `col-**-pull-**` classes you change column order moving using `left` or `right` properties.

You can try like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">
        Header Content Middle
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">
        Header Content Right
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8">
        Header Content Left
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example in Codepen is [here](http://codepen.io/neilhem/pen/CwtlG)

P.S. One thing to know I have changed column order in my example to achieve right column order when columns are collapsed.

Comment: Good answer, but it would be made better by explaining what the `pull-*` and `push-*` classes do as it may not be immediately obvious to the OP

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as well, i've done some reading and I think i've got the hang of it

Answer (score 6):

To extend neilhem's answer, the [push and pull](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) modifiers are what you're looking for.

From the doc:

> Easily change the order of our built-in grid columns with .col-md-push-* and .col-md-pull-* modifier classes.

Basically, what these modifiers do is push (move to the right) or pull (move to the left) the column based on the offset you supply, where the starting point is based on the order of the column within the row. It can be read like this:

```css
/* column  size  direction  offset */
   .col    -sm   -push      -4
```

So for your example you'd want something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <!--first column so start at 0 then push it to the right 4 -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">
       Header Content Middle
    </div>

    <!-- start at 4 then push to the right 4 -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4"> 
        Header Content Right
    </div>

    <!-- start at 8 then pull to the left 8 -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8">
        Header Content Left
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/folum/1/edit?html,output)**

---

Here is a visual breakdown of what's going on step-by-step:

1. before reordering:

   ```
   [    column 1    ][    column 2    ][    column 3    ]
   ```

   [example](http://jsbin.com/folum/2/edit?html,output)
2. push the first column 4 offsets:

   ```
   [    offset 4    ][   column 1-2   ][    column 3    ]
                         ^ they are on top of each other at this point
   ```

   [example](http://jsbin.com/folum/3/edit?html,output)
3. push the second column 4 offsets:

   ```
   [     offset 4    ][    column 1    ][  column 2-3   ]
                                           ^ they are on top of each other at this point
   ```

   [example](http://jsbin.com/folum/4/edit?html,output)
4. pull the third column 8 offsets:

   ```
   [     column 3    ][    column 1    ][  column 2     ]
         ^ column 3 falls into the open offset caused by column 1's push
   ```

   [example](http://jsbin.com/folum/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

use pull/push classes like this to achieve what you want:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">
        Header Content Left
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">
        Header Content Middle
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">
        Header Content Right
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1040/